# error for INSERT using SELECT in PROCEDURE (PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, procedure

I'm getting error with running this procedure in PL/SQL (Oracle) in my own schema:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO myschema.mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4)
  SELECT COUNT(*), col2, col3, col4
  FROM AnotherSchema.anotherTable
  GROUP BY AnotherSchema.anotherTable.col2;

END my_procedure;
```

These are the errors I get:

Error(4,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Error(6,22): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

AnotherSchema.anotherTable does exist. and so does myschema.mytable

in fact, when I just run the INSERT command, it works fine and a row gets inserted into myschema.mytable :

```
  INSERT INTO myschema.mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4)
  SELECT COUNT(*), col2, col3, col4
  FROM AnotherSchema.anotherTable
  GROUP BY AnotherSchema.anotherTable.col2;
```

I don't understand why I get this error when i put the INSERT function inside the procedure.

---

EDIT:

I need to clarify that I am running the script in my own schema and inserting into a table that was created by myself in my own schema. and I can perform select  (from my schema) on the table I'm reading from AnotherSchema.

Comment: First of all, try grouping correctly, like so: `GROUP BY AnotherSchema.anotherTable.col2, AnotherSchema.anotherTable.col3, AnotherSchema.anotherTable.col4`. You can get this error, if the user you're calling this procedure from doesn't have read privileges on that table; are you running it withthe same user?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Obviously, that was a typo, as it's clear that I'm only providing pseudo script in my post, and not the actual script. I have corrected this in my post. And yes, i'm reading the table with the same user and I have read priviledges on that table (AnotherSchema.aotherTable).

Comment: Well, pseudo script doesn't work either, better give a more close approximation of the real script or the script itself. My question remains about the users you're running this with though. The error is clear to me - starting at line 4 (the statement), and followed by `ORA-942` at line 6 - `AnotherSchema.anotherTable`. The schema where you defined `my_procedure` is probably different than the one you use for the `INSERT` statement on its own.

Comment: No, I'm running the create procedure script in my own schema. and I have select privilege on AnotherSchema tables. and as i said, when I highlight the INSERT section of the script (in my own schema) and run it, it works. But when I run the whole script (in my own schema) it doesn't work.

Comment: grant select on AnotherSchema.anotherTable to myschema?

Comment: something is missing, if you granting directly like above, it will work, I tried

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I got admin to grant select my schema and it works now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not been granted the select privilege to the tables in the other schema directly but probably through a role, for your insert to work inside PLSQL, you will need the direct Grant to select on those tables.

Here is a link from Ask Tom explaining why it is like that:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this a bit more? I have a feeling that might be the culprit eventhough I don't quite understand it. I'm trying to run the whole script in my own Schema and I get the error. But when I highlight just the INSERT section of the script and run that, it works fine. How could I not have direct Grant access to INSERT into a table in my own schema that I have created and am running the script from my own schema?

Comment: makes sense now. As @Thomas also suggested, I got admin to grant select my schema and now it works. Many thanks for the link and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If it says the table/view does not exist then it might be that you have misspelled the table name while using in procedure.

Secondly if table name is correct please ensure the myschema has the select privileges on AnotherSchema.anotherTable . On the record got inserted check if you ran the insert statement in myschema or anotherschema.

Comment: table name is fine. as i said, when I highlight the middle section (the insert command) and run that section only, it's fine. I only get the error when I run the whole thing with create or replace procedure.

I obviously have select privileges on AnotherSchema.anotherTable because when I'm running the INSERT section of command in my own schema, it works.